# Finding all Circular path for undirected graph created using networkx

Tags: python-3.x, networkx

I am creating a undirected graph using networkx. I want to find all the possible circular path for specific nodes?
Is there any way to get those because I am unable to find a way?

Comment: Can you post sample data and expected it results?  Look at [networkx.algorithms.cycles.find_cycle](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.cycles.find_cycle.html).

Comment: . For ex :- (0->1,1->2,2->3,0->3,16->17,17->18,18->19,0->16,16->19,19->3,1->17,2->18)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx

df = pd.DataFrame({'Source':[0,1,2,0,16,17,18,0,16,19,1,2],'Target':[1,2,3,3,17,18,19,16,19,3,17,18]})

G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, 'Source', 'Target')

nx.cycles.find_cycle(G)
```

Output:

```
[(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 0)]
```